# Preprint request etiquette

Tags: etiquette, collaboration, preprint

I am collaborating on a disability advocacy project with someone, let's call her A, who was told by medical researcher B:

> Some collaborators and I have an article coming out soon which would lend strong support to your project.  I will write you a summary report of our findings and send it to you soon.

I would like to look at the whole article asap to evaluate how well it fits with our project, and to see whether we should make any adjustments to what we have already written, in other words, to incorporate some of B's data and interpretation into our project.  B is reportedly concerned that the government official that A and I are working with (and working on) will not have the time and inclination to read the article itself.  There is an undercurrent of ivory tower snobbery.  (Background information: A is extremely knowledgeable about the disability and is a skilled advocate but she's not strong on reading journal articles on our topic.)

Ideally, from my point of view, B shares the preprint with us and lets us decide whether to submit it along with, or instead of, the summary.  (I do not have direct communication with B.)

1. What is technically permitted?  Supposedly the article has been accepted for publication.  If that is true, is B permitted to share a preprint?
2. What is the etiquette for requesting a preprint?

Comment: Question 1 probably depends more on the publication venue and its terms & conditions. As for question 2 -- what do you mean by "etiquette"? Isn't a simple email saying "hi, saw your article listed on the conference/journal proceedings and was hoping I could get a preprint" enough?

Comment: Question 1 has nothing to do with the publication process, but rather with the coauthors if there are any. (At least in math.) But I'd be careful with statements like "which would lend strong support" before seeing the preprint. Perhaps, once you see it, you decide it is not worth the support anymore? (Abstracts and talks tend to create overly strong expectations for the content of the work, even in exact disciplines such as mathematics. Not to mention that you may discover the methods to be flawed or worse.)

Comment: @tonysdg - But I didn't see it listed anywhere.  I heard about it from collaborator A.

Comment: @darijgrinberg - You've hit the nail on the head.  I completely understand that B would be excited about her study.  But I need to see it myself, and since we're trying to get our project out the door quickly, I need to see it *soon*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. It depends on the agreement between the author and the publisher.  However, I've never heard of a case where an author would not be allowed to share a preprint privately.  (Some publishers do forbid preprints to be posted on public websites or repositories.)
2. Since the author has already expressed willingness to share a summary, I would write something like:

> I appreciate your taking the time to prepare a summary.  If you would be willing to share a preprint of the article itself, I would find that very helpful as well.  Otherwise, I will look forward to reading it when it is published.

Comment: I used this as a starting point and changed it a little bit.  I wrote an email to B, and sent it to A, asking her to forward it to B.  She did, but we have received nothing from B.  However, C (another collaborator of A's) sent us two papers that don't help at all.  (I had already found four papers that lend specific support to our proposal, that are a much better fit.)  So, we will finalize without any input from B.  At least we tried.